# How to load content in a "virtual window" like "LightBox"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I like how Lightbox does that overlay window that displays the full size image link. Is there a way to load an html file like that? I would like to have pictures, text, maybe an embedded youtube video too all able to load in that "Virtual Window", Vertical scrolling would be nice too.  I would like to avoid jquery or other things like that. Like just Java, html, and css would be nice. But if that isn't possible I can handle calling the jquery if need be.

Thanks in advance to all you savvy people!

Eva

Comment: I think fancybox, thickbox, and a hand full of other jquery modal plugins have options for that. Try searching for some and pick the one that works best for you.

Comment: Not using a jQuery plugin is commendable, but it would require a lot of work. An iframe could be a (sad) solution. Otherwise go with @JeffPowers suggestion

Comment: Are you sure you meant [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#JavaScript_and_Java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I've spent a lot of time trying to find nice no-jQuery lightbox. And I only needed to display images, not videos or HTML. My searches failed so in the end I had to give up and include jQuery in my site.

Once you give up have a look at [Jquery Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

It has directly implemented display of images, YouTube or other videos as well as dynamically loaded HTML. See their [examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/).

Unfortunatelly, this library requires [JQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: The "Outside HTML (Ajax)" Would be perfect! How do I go about having that one work?

Comment: Display the example page source. I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do. Keep in mind that it requires *jQuery*, so it's not exacly what you originally wanted.

Comment: Yeah I figure you're right about not being able to find another way, I can do jQuery. I just want to call an HTML file like the Homer one is.

Comment: Well, then check the example (Ctrl+U shows page source, lines 21 and 68) and do it similary. I can't you tell more without exploring it myself, and that's, Eva, really rather your job than mine :)

Comment: Yay! :D Thank you very much :) Now to get my tweak on! 

I'd vote up but I am too newbie I guess...first post and all.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, but if you believe my answer was correct, you may mark it as **the** answer using that grey checkmark under voting buttons.